# Скрипт добавления сайта на главный экран мобильного или стационарных устройств

Tags: javascript

Существуют ли в природе методы изготовления кнопки, при нажатии на которую произойдет добавление иконки сайта на "Главный экран" или "Рабочий стол"? Аналог встроенного функционала браузера, с размещением иконки.

Comment: Существуют, разумеется. Взять для примера мобильную версию VK, которая предлагает "добавить ярлык для быстрого доступа" на главный экран. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#best-practices

Comment: @smellyshovel, спасибо, это я видел. Вот [это](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen) тоже видел. Но, интересует возможность реализации не только на мобильных устройствах + по нажатию, а не всплывающим при входе.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется Progressive Web Application (сокращённо PWA).

Для того, чтобы оно работало, требуется настроить манифест и сервис-вёкер. Если не ошибаюсь, настроить их надо таким образом, чтобы была возможна оффлайновая работа.

Ну и пара ссылок:

- https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/
- https://netology.ru/blog/progressive-web-apps
- https://medium.com/dailyjs/goodbye-electron-hello-desktop-pwas-f316b8f39882

Comment: О это, уже что-то. Спасибо!